# Join two dataframes on the values present in a specific column in the name_data dataframe using koalas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, databricks, spark-koalas

I am trying to join two the dataframes as shown below on the `code` column values present in the `name_data` dataframe.

I have two dataframes shown below and I expect to have a resulting dataframe which would only have the rows from the `team_data`dataframe where the corresponding`code`value column is present in the`name_data``` dataframe.

I am using koalas for this on databricks and I have the following code using the join operation.

```
import databricks.koalas as ks

name_data= ks.DataFrame({'code':['123a', '345b', '678c'],
        'id':[1, 2, 3]})

team_data = ks.DataFrame({'code':['123a', '23s', '34a'],
        'id':[1, 2, 3]})

team_data_filtered = team_data.join(name_data.set_index('code'), on='code')

display(team_data_filtered)
```

The expected output would be to see only the following in `team_data_filtered`.

```
Code    id
'123a'   1
```

But my code is throwing an error stating that  `columns overlap but no suffix specified: ['id']`.

May someone help to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding suffix parameters:

```
team_data_filtered = team_data.join(name_data.set_index('code'), on='code', 
                                                lsuffix='_1', rsuffix='_2')
team_data_filtered = team_data_filtered.loc[team_data_filtered.id_1==team_data_filtered.id2]
display(team_data_filtered)
```

An then to clean the columns, if desired:

```
team_data_filtered.rename({'id_1':'id'}, inplace=True, axis=1)
```

Comment: what does the lsuffix and rsuffix do? and what does the _1 and _2 mean?

Comment: For any join where the non "on" columns have the same name, a suffix is required (l or r, for left or right) to append a string suffix to its name.  I updated to clean up the dataframe after processing the join

Comment: I tried to do sth as the following: ```team_data_filtered = name_data.join(team_data.set_index('code'), on='code', 
                                                lsuffix='_1', rsuffix='_2').dropna().drop(['*_1','*_2'])```. I try to drop all the columns that start with *_1 and *_2 as detailed in the suffix, I am not sure what this does not work as it says invalid syntax in drop(). May you help me resolve it?

Comment: You'd probably only want to drop one, and rename another?  In any event the syntax wouldn't be '*_2' but 'id_2', for example, or ['id_1', 'id_2'].  If you had more columns you could do : drop([i + '_2' for i in dataframe.columns])

Comment: how do i rename all the columns with suffix _1 using the code rather than hardcoding the values as I can have many columns in the dataframe?

Comment: You can chain them, such as:  team_data_filtered.drop([i for i in team_data_filtered.columns if i.endswith('_1')])

Answer (score 0):

```
name_data= ps.DataFrame({'code':['123a', '345b', '678c'],
                         'id':[1, 2, 3]})

team_data = ps.DataFrame({'code':['123a', '23s', '34a'],
                          'id':[1, 2, 3]})

team_data_filtered = team_data.join(name_data.set_index('code'),how='inner', on='code',rsuffix="_2")

team_data_filtered.drop("id_2",axis=1).to_spark().show()
```

out：

```
+----+---+
|code| id|
+----+---+
|123a|  1|
+----+---+
```